# Google reCAPTCHA not working in .NET WebForms

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, recaptcha

Trying to included a google reCAPTCHA in one of my web pages but I am getting the error (in chromes developer tools):

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Missing required parameters: sitekey

at new dz (recaptcha__en.js:272)

at new GB (recaptcha__en.js:511)

at Object.Rw [as render] (recaptcha__en.js:509)

at renderRecaptcha (recaptchatest:93)

Here is my aspx design code;

```
<div id="ReCaptchContainer"></div> 
            <asp:Label ID="lblMEssage" runat="server" clientidmode="static"></asp:Label>
        <br />  
            <asp:Button type="button" ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
```

Here is my JS and jQuery:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=renderRecaptcha&render=explicit" async defer></script>

    <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript">  
        var your_site_key = '<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["6LfaeeoUAAAAAAhiEswkFeJ278PnF3-XXXXXXXXX"]%>';  
        var renderRecaptcha = function () {  
            grecaptcha.render('ReCaptchContainer', {  
                'sitekey': your_site_key,  
                'callback': reCaptchaCallback,  
                theme: 'light', //light or dark    
                type: 'image',// image or audio    
                size: 'normal'//normal or compact    
            });  
        };  

        var reCaptchaCallback = function (response) {  
            if (response !== '') {  
                jQuery('#lblMessage').css('color', 'green').html('Success');  
            }  
        };  

        jQuery('button[type="button"]').click(function(e) {  
            var message = 'Please checck the checkbox';  
            if (typeof (grecaptcha) != 'undefined') {  
                var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();  
                (response.length === 0) ? (message = 'Captcha verification failed') : (message = 'Success!');  
            }  
            jQuery('#lblMessage').html(message);  
            jQuery('#lblMessage').css('color', (message.toLowerCase() == 'success!') ? "green" : "red");  
        });  

    </script>
```

Note I have altered the last 9 digits of my API key.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the key you use for application settings is wrong:

```
var your_site_key = '<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["6LfaeeoUAAAAAAhiEswkFeJ278PnF3-XXXXXXXXX"]%>';
```

Perhaps it should be something like `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["your-key"]` and returned value should be `"6LfaeeoUAAAAAAhiEswkFeJ278PnF3-XXXXXXXXX"`?

UPDATE: `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["your-key"]` is used to load configuration from `web.config` `<appSettings>` section. If you don't use application settings, then all you need is to add your key directly:

```
var your_site_key = "6LfaeeoUAAAAAAhiEswkFeJ278PnF3-XXXXXXXXX";
```

Comment: I tried this - var your_site_key = AppSettings["6LfaeeoUAAAAAAhiEswkFeJ278PnF3-XXXXXXXXX"]; And got the error - Uncaught ReferenceError: AppSettings is not defined
    at recaptchatest:91

Comment: This is big missunderstanding. Do you know what is `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` for? Do you have `web.config` file with `<appSettings>` in your project?